# Issue with changing colour of material-ui card icons

Tags: javascript, css

I have an issue with changing the background colour of the cards icon from Material UI. I am trying to change the colour but when I attempt to change it, only 2 cards get changed. I tried to fix the problem but I can find the issue. I tried browsing for solutions from other posts, but they weren't really helpful for in my scenario.

[image: Here's the before photo]

[image: Here's the photo after trying to add a background:]

My .css and .js file:.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Card, CardContent, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./InfoBox.css";

function InfoBox({ title, cases, total, active, isRed, ...props }) {
  console.log(title, active);
  return (
    <Card
      onClick={props.onClick}
      className={`infoBox ${active && "infoBox--selected"} ${
        isRed && "infoBox--red"
      }`}
    >
      <CardContent>
        <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
          {title}
        </Typography>
        <h2 className={`infoBox__cases ${!isRed && "infoBox__cases--green"}`}>
          {cases}
        </h2>

        <Typography className="infoBox__total" color="textSecondary">
          {total} Total
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default InfoBox;
```

```css
.infoBox {
  flex: 1;
}

.infoBox:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}

.infoBox--selected {
  border-top: 10px solid greenyellow;
}

.infoBox--red {
  border-color: #cc2507;
}

.infoBox__cases--green {
  color: lightgreen !important;
}

.infoBox__cases {
  color: #cc2507;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.infoBox__total {
  color: #c4c2c2;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  font-size: 0.8rem !important;
  margin-top: 15px !important;
}
```

Comment: You're changing the color for `.infoBox:not(:last-child)` (all except the last one). Do it in `.infoBox` instead

Comment: I’ve tried changing it for .infoBox but it still doesn’t work